# Call a c# method from Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, methods

Hi i want to call a C# method.. I already tryed with webmethod, but in the c# method i will not have acces to textbox or others controls.

this is how i done without success..
http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx

With static works, but i want without static, so i can access to the controls in the aspx and validate the page.

how can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this with just a javascript call, you need to postback if you want access to the controls on the page.  The page doesn't know what's in the textboxes for example unless you send that data, which a javascript call won't do, but a form or AJAX submit will.

I'd suggest a javascript validation library, [something like this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).  Just be sure to also validate on the server once you've submitted to check for users who have javascript disabled (or are maliciously trying to bypass your validation...).

Comment: If you use an UpdatePanel the ajax will basically post back all the data without refreshing the page... Which isn't all the great

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at how to use an [UpdatePanel](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/tutorials/IntroductionUpdatePanel.aspx), or a straight [ajax callback](http://www.developertutorials.com/learn-ajax/ajax-callback-function-2641.php).

With the UpdatePanel, you go through most of the page lifecycle, so you have access to the textboxes etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using an [UpdatePanel](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx) may be the simplest path to what you're trying to accomplish.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>

    ... your controls ...

  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```